# lvm mirror doesn't resync the logical volulme

Tags: linux, redhat, lvm

I trying to restore one lvm mirror using the old metadata, for restore the config i'm using the command

```
vgcfgrestore -f redhat vgmirror
```

but after the restore of the old metadata, the resync doesn't start and after i used this the command

```
vgchange --refresh vgmirror
```

The lvs -ao +devices reports the status of the in 100% sync

Before restore the metadata the volume was linear volume, why lvm doesn't resync the sync?

For me isn't normale, i change the config the config of logical volume and i changed one object from linear to mirror and anything happen and i see the sync 100%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this can help someone with same problem, now in redhat 6.5 and later, is possible to triger the volume sync after restore the old volume group state.

```
vgcfgrestore -f myconfing.cfg vg01 #this is my old config for the mirror volumes
vgchange --refresh vg01 #i say to lvm to reread the restored metadata of vg01
```

I did a test in redhat 7 and it work, in redhat 5 i found the problem posted in my question.